# BindingExpression path error when creating the Window (no VM bound yet)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to follow the MVVM pattern, but I'm having a hard time binding a VM property to a dependency property of a UserControl of mine. I'm not sure whether I got the initialization flow completely wrong or I just missed a detail.

Here is my Application Startup event handler:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel();
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    viewModel.BindView(window);
    window.Show();
}
```

This is my `MainViewModel` (`ViewModelBase` comes from MVVM Light):

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Project m_currentProject = new Project();
    public Project CurrentProject
    {
        get { return m_currentProject; }
        private set
        {
            m_currentProject = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WST_Desktop.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WST_Desktop"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WST_Desktop.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="540" Width="960">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <controls:ProjectControl Project="{Binding Path=CurrentProject, Converter={wstd:DebugConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I get this error from the DataBinding Listener (lines broken for readability):

```
BindingExpression path error: 'CurrentProject' property not found on 'object' ''Project' (HashCode=30400195)'. 
BindingExpression:Path=CurrentProject; DataItem='Project' (HashCode=30400195); 
target element is 'ProjectControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Project' (type 'Project')
```

The error is reported on the line with `new MainWindow()` from the startup handler. Also, the `DebugConverter` I attached to the binding is never hit.

I think I understand that the MainWindow is created without a DataContext (it will be bound in the next line), and so it fails binding the property of the ViewModel (that it doesn't know of yet, of course). Am I correct? How do I fix this?

**PS**
Of course, the `ProjectControl` has a public property named `Project` of the correct `Project` type.

**And** this is the `BindView` method that gets called in the Startup event handler:

```
public static void BindView(this ViewModelBase viewModel, Control i_control)
{
    i_control.DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Which basically translates to

```
window.DataContext = viewModel;
```

---

**MORE INFO**

I tried to change this

```
<controls:ProjectControl Project="{Binding Path=CurrentProject, Converter={wstd:DebugConverter}}" />
```

to this

```
<controls:ProjectControl DataContext="{Binding Path=CurrentProject, Converter={wstd:DebugConverter}}" />
```

and the error is gone. I'm not sure which one is correct, though: should the `Project` object (which is sort of the "root" model object of my `ProjectControl`) be a dependency property or the DataContext?

Comment: I suppose there is something that causes this binding error but it's not in your sample you posted here. This looks OK and shouldn't cause any binding errors. You're probably setting the `DataContext` property of your window somewhere in code or in XAML (before calling your `BindView` method). Look for that.

Comment: @dymanoid You're right. In the `ProjectControl`'s constructor I was initializing a DataContext - something that stayed there from a test. Now I've removed that, but the error above still comes out two lines later, on the `window.Show()`, when the DataContext of `window` is set. Any idea?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It is hard to tell what is wrong when you're not showing all the related code. At least, we need your `ProjectControl` and its `Project` property implementation.

Comment: @dymanoid Never mind, I actually get a different error - which I can hardly deal with, but that would be another question :) Please make an answer of your comment, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what this binding error is all about:

> BindingExpression path error: 'CurrentProject' property not found on
>   'object' ''Project' (HashCode=30400195)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=CurrentProject; DataItem='Project'
>   (HashCode=30400195);
>   target element is 'ProjectControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Project' (type 'Project')

You can get a lot of info out of it.

First of all, the Binding Engine is telling you that there is an error in the `Path` property of your `Binding`, because the Binding Engine cannot find a property named `CurrentProject` on an object that is serving as current `DataContext`. You should know, that the Binding Engine uses the `DataContext` object as the source when you don't explicitly specify a different source (e.g. using `ElementName` or `Source` properties of the `Binding`).

The Binding Engine states also, that the current `DataContext` object is of type `Project` and not of type `MainViewModel`. It is the fact that should make you look suspicious at the code.

The second line just repeats the info: the `DataContext` (or `DataItem` in this message) is an object of type `Project`, and we're trying to get its property `CurrentProject` (what is obviously not possible, because this property doesn't exist).

The third line shows you your `Binding`'s target: it is an object of type `ProjectControl` and its property named `Project` (of type `Project`).

So summarizing: the view model the Binding Engine is dealing with is not the one you're thinking you're binding to. There is only one explanation for this: somewhere, there's some code or another `Binding` that sets the view's `DataContext` to an object of type `Project`.

And as you mention in the comment, you have found that in your code.

Comment: Thanks, problem fixed.

Answer (score 2):

What is this `BindView` method?

Just try

```
window.DataContext = viewModel;
```

Instead of

```
viewModel.BindView(window);
```

Edit: Okay as the error message states you are looking for a `CurrentProject` property on an object of type `Project`. I would suggest you bind the `DataContext` of your `Grid` to your `viewmodel` aswell. This should solve your problem.

To verify that solves your problem you can just adjust the binding

```
 <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=foo, Path=DataContext}">
```

and set the name of your window `Name="foo"`.

Comment: See my edit for explainations. The `BindView` method does just that.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, I get the same error.